# After how long is a JW called inactive?

Tags: jehovahs-witnesses

Does anyone know for sure after how long of being inactive is a Jehovah's Witness announced officially as being inactive?

Answer (score 4):

Inactive means the person has stopped sharing in our primary vocation, the preaching of the Good news of The Kingdom (Matthew 24:14)
This means they are not talking to non witnesses about their faith. There is no announcement made regarding this.

I can’t find a shareable source  right now but if a baptized witness fails to report any witnessing activity for 6 consecutive months he is considered inactive.

The subject of inactivity is addressed in the [about us][1] section of our website.
Here we find that the number of Jehovah’s Witnesses reported in a given year comes from each country’s peak or highest month of persons reporting participation in the preaching activity. So if an individual is not reporting preaching activity during their country’s peak month they are not part of that years total number of active JW’s.

Whether one has stopped preaching for months or years, after being baptized, the only time an announcement is made regarding a person no longer being one of Jehovah’s Witnesses is if they are disfellowshipped for unrepentant serious sin or they disassociate themselves by requesting to no longer be identified as one of Jehovah’s Witnesses.

Being inactive does not mean the person is no longer one of Jehovah’s Witnesses. In fact special effort is made to reach out to those who have drifted away

Comment: While inactive ones are still considered Jehovah's Witnesses, they are not counted as such in the yearly service reports for the number of Witnesses. [How Many of Jehovah’s Witnesses Are There Worldwide?](https://www.jw.org/finder?wtlocale=E&docid=502016131&srcid=share)

Comment: @4castle  thanks that is an important point. However once one has publicly identified as one of Jehovah’s Witnesses at baptism there is no announcement  regarding their status changing unless they disassociate or are disfellowshipped.  I will edit in a link to the FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

A search on the official JW web site provided this information under the heading INACTIVITY:

> Can They Be Helped?   We were happy to learn from last month’s Our Kingdom Ministry that there will be an increased effort during the coming months to help those who have stopped sharing the truth with others. Many of these no longer attend meetings...  Many who have become inactive are not opposed to the truth but have stopped associating due to personal problems and discouragement.  (February 1982 Our Kingdom Ministry) Source: https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/201982047#h=1:0-11:564

Clearly, any Witness who has become inactive (has stopped coming to meetings and going from house to house) will be encouraged to return.  No announcement is made of inactivity.  Inactivity should not be confused with DISASSOCIATION which is announced to the congregation:

> 30 The term “disassociation” applies to the action taken by a person who is a baptized member of the congregation but deliberately repudiates his Christian standing by stating that he no longer wants to be recognized as, or known as, one of Jehovah’s Witnesses. Or he might renounce his place in the Christian congregation by his actions, such as by becoming part of a secular organization that has objectives contrary to Bible teachings and therefore is under judgment by Jehovah God.—Isa. 2:4; Rev. 19:17-21.
>
> 31 Concerning those who renounced their Christian faith in his day, the apostle John wrote: “They went out from us, but they were not of our sort; for if they had been of our sort, they would have remained with us.”—1 John 2:19.
>
> 32 When a person is disassociated, his situation before Jehovah is far different from that of an inactive Christian, one who no longer shares in the field ministry. A person may have become inactive because he failed to study God’s Word regularly. Or perhaps he experienced personal problems or persecution and lost his zeal for serving Jehovah. The elders as well as others in the congregation will continue to render appropriate spiritual assistance to an inactive Christian.—Rom. 15:1; 1 Thess. 5:14; Heb. 12:12.
>
> 33 In contrast, if a person who is a Christian chooses to disassociate himself, a brief announcement is made to inform the congregation, stating: “[Name of person] is no longer one of Jehovah’s Witnesses.” Such a person is treated in the same way as a disfellowshipped person. The coordinator of the body of elders should approve this announcement. (Organized to do Jehovah’s Will p 142-143) Source: https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1102014944#h=44:0-44:348

No mention is made of how long it takes for a JW publisher to be considered inactive although Kris is probably right to suggest six months.